# Background drawable error

Tags: android, xml, background, drawable

I have an application with some kind of switchbutton, it actually is 2 textviews align at the center of the screen, I am having a problem, while I was testing the app in a JB device it all work fine, but when I tested in some GB devices the background of the textviews was messed up. 
This is how is showing on the JellyBean device, how it should look:

[image: This is how it has to look like]

And this is how it is showing on the GingerBread devices:
[image: This is how it is showing]

Any idea what can be happening?

These are the relevant parts of the xml files:

layout_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Layout_driver_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Layout_Profile"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Libre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_libre"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"            
            android:text="Libre"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_NoDisponible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_no_disponible"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"       
            android:text="No Disponible"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

drawable/Background_libre.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners 
                android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"                
                 />
            <solid android:color="@color/libre_verde" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

drawable/Background_no_disponible.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="6dp" 
                     android:topRightRadius="6dp" 
                    />
            <solid android:color="@color/no_disponible_plomo" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug. Switch left with right for version 12 and under.

Like this:

```
<corners 
   android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
   android:bottomRightRadius="6dp" />
```

Similarly for the second drawable.

You will have to place these edited(left and right reversed) drawables in `res/drawable-v12` folder. Create it if it isn't present. Your regular drawables (one you posted above) will remain in `red/drawable` folder.

Bug is filed at: [Link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161).

Comment: I'm doing it, but still have no results.

Comment: @El_Mochiq Can you post your updated xml code? I also think that only bottom_X_Radius need to be switched, top ones are not affected by the bug.

Comment: I read the discussion in the Link you posted, now it's working fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you put both textviews in a a LinearLayout, and you set the corner radii on the inner LinearLayout?

To clarify:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout
        android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:topRightRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
        ... >

        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since the Layout is wrapping the content, the edge of the textviews is showing and the borders are not showing rounded.